# Calculator API's in search

Tags: rest, azure, calculator, google-cloud-platform, azure-cloud-services

I am just trying to figure out some kind of API's which my app can use for infrastructure calculation. Something like this, provided by [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/).

I tried googling and couldn't find anything related. I don't want anything which requires a subscription to be calculated, as this might be used by public who doesnt have any cloud account. Anyone aware about the same for Azure and Google Cloud?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, no such thing exists in Azure (haven't worked with Google, so I am not sure about that) as available in AWS.

Azure does have a [`Rate Card API`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219005.aspx) but to access it, you would need an active Azure Subscription.

Though not an API based access, but Azure does have a decent [`Pricing Calculator`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/) that can give a rough idea about how much it is going to cost you for hosting resources in Azure.

Comment: Thanks, so if I have a subscription, can I get all the azure products pricing through API calls (even if I am not using any Azure services in that subscription)? Basically I am trying to create a calculator. That's why I need an API.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You can look through all the SKUs Azure offers and get rate cards for those. Once you have the rate card, you should be able to build a calculator.

Comment: Is there any cost for this rate card.? I don't think so.. I didnt see anywhere as well.. But just to confirm..

Comment: If by cost you mean "are you charged anything for accessing this api" then the answer is no at this point of time. However, there's a limit on the number of API calls you make per subscription. Currently it is 15000 reads / hour (Ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits).